# Clicking on second accordion first accordion is not closing by default

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i am using bootstrap accordion for expanding and displaying the text.Accordion is working fine but when clicking on the second accordion the first one is not closing automatically.It should be closed automatically.Here is my code for that

```
<div class="accordion" id="myAccordion">
                <button type="button" class="servicesecommerce" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-1" data-parent="#myAccordion">E-Commerce Development</button><br/>
                <div id="collapsible-1"   class="collapse" >
                    <div class="services3">When it comes to e-Commerce websites you need a partner that is focused and experienced in providing companies the best in professional e-Commerce web design solutions. With a team of experts under one roof, Teknotrait goal is to provide you with all of the necessary design, development and marketing services you need to be successful online.</div>                           
                    <div class="services5">We build E-Commerce Shopping Cart Applications, E-Commerce store front & custom e-commerce shopping cart development solutions.</div>
                    <div class="services6">Teknotrait will help you to build a simple, efficient and familiar shopping interface that can include a number of useful security features such as SSL-A Secure Socket Layer, as the first line of defence against online intruders, utilizing a public-and-private key 128-bit encryption system to uniquely identify individuals carrying out transactions on your website.</div>                         
                    <div class="services7">Our e-commerce development includes Dedicated SSL Certificate compliance that assures your visitors that your site is secure and that their personal information will remain private so they can conduct secure Internet transactions with confidence.</div>                 
                </div>

<button type="button" class="servicesmobile" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-3" data-parent="#myAccordion">Mobile App Development</button><br/>                    
                <div id="collapsible-4" class="collapse" >                                                  
                    <div class="services3">Mobile application development refers the process of developing application or software for the mobiles, personal digital assistants and other handheld devices. When it comes to provide mobile application development services to the required clients, we come at the first position. There is no doubt that mobile technology is incredibly gaining popularity in the market and organizations started making presence in this sector</div>                         
                    <div class="services5">Empowering modern day enterprises, we Teknotrait Solution offer custom business & enterprise mobile apps development solutions which provide better potential and makes the business environment more transparent, intelligent, communication and work flow assistant for user. With our innovative and business – driven approach we work as a companion for the entrepreneurs to thrive and achieve much bigger business perspectives.</div>                   
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Accordion</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
     margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Accordion</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
     margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any difference between your 2 examples? please also add an explanation. Second no need to make 2 answers.

Comment: did you get mad because i made a comment and then downvoted me?